# Barnes' double gamma function versus q-gamma function

Tags: special-functions, q-analogs

According to wikipedia, the [q-analog of the gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-gamma_function) is closely related to a [multiple gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_gamma_function) defined by Barnes. Besides the fact that they are both generalizations of the Gamma function, I fail to see a precise relation. How are these functions related?

Answer (score 0):

q-Pochhammer symbol has the following representation:
$$(q^w;q)_{\infty}=\frac{\Gamma_2(w|1,\tau')\Gamma_2(w|1,-\tau')}{\Gamma_1(w|1)}.$$